# Very strange error in my C++ program

Tags: c++, windows

My program that I have completed worked just fine before I inserted the math portion of it. After I completed the math portion I built the code and no errors came up. However, when I tried to debug my program and I got this prompt:" Unhandled exception at 0x4f7ccb1a (msvcr100d.dll) in Reciept.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x4e65ab48."

I first thought that it was the math but then I deleted it and ran the program again, and what was supposed to come up like it did before didn't. That same prompt came up.

Can you please tell me what's going on.

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

struct menuItemType
{
    string menuItem;
    double menuPrice;
    double sum;
    double amountTotal;
    double tax;
};

void getData(menuItemType menuList[8]);
void printCheck(menuItemType menuList[8]);
void showMenu(menuItemType menuList[8]);

int main()
{
    menuItemType menuList[8];
    getData(menuList);
    showMenu(menuList);
    printCheck(menuList);

    system ("pause");
    return 0;
}

void getData(menuItemType menuList[8])
{
    menuList[1].menuItem = "Plain Egg"; 
    menuList[1].menuPrice = 1.45;
    menuList[2].menuItem = "Bacon and Egg";
    menuList[2].menuPrice = 2.45;
    menuList[3].menuItem = "Muffin";
    menuList[3].menuPrice = 0.99;
    menuList[4].menuItem = "French Toast";
    menuList[4].menuPrice = 1.99;
    menuList[5].menuItem = "Fruit Basket";
    menuList[5].menuPrice = 2.49;
    menuList[6].menuItem = "Cereal";
    menuList[6].menuPrice = 0.69;
    menuList[7].menuItem = "Coffee";
    menuList[7].menuPrice = 0.50;
    menuList[8].menuItem = "Tea";
    menuList[8].menuPrice = 0.75;
}

 void showMenu(menuItemType menuList[8])
 {
    cout << "Please enter the numbers  beside the product that you 
        would like to  have today.
        When you are finished press 0.\n" << endl;
    cout << "1 - Plain Egg" << setw(14) << "$1.45" << endl;
    cout << "2 - Bacon and Egg" << setw(10) << "$2.45" << endl;
    cout << "3 - Muffin" << setw(17) << "$0.99" << endl;
    cout << "4 - French Toast" << setw(11) << "$1.99" << endl;
    cout << "5 - Fruit Basket" << setw(11) << "$2.49" << endl;
    cout << "6 - Cereal" << setw(17) << "$0.69" << endl;
    cout << "7 - Coffee" << setw(17) << "$0.50" << endl;
    cout << "8 - Tea" << setw(21) << "$0.75\n" << endl;
}

void printCheck(menuItemType menuList[8])
{
    int selections = 1;

    while(selections != 0)
    {
        cout << "\n Please enter one of the choice from our menu: ";
        selections += selections;
        cin >> selections;

        switch(selections)
        {
            case 0:
            break;

            case 1:
            cout << menuList[1].menuItem << setw(14) << "$1.45";
            break;
            case 2:
            cout << menuList[2].menuItem << setw(10) << "$2.45";
            break;
            case 3:
            cout << menuList[3].menuItem << setw(17) << "$0.99";
            break;
            case 4:
            cout << menuList[4].menuItem << setw(11) << "$1.99";
            break;
            case 5:
            cout << menuList[5].menuItem << setw(11) << "$2.49";
            break;
            case 6:
            cout << menuList[6].menuItem << setw(17) << "$0.69";
            break;
            case 7:
            cout << menuList[7].menuItem << setw(17) << "$0.50";
            break;
            case 8:
            cout << menuList[8].menuItem << setw(20) << "$0.75";
            break;
            default:
            cout << "The number you just enter is not between 1 and 8. Please try again.\n";
            break;


            //  const double tax = 0.05; 
            int x;
            double amountTotal = 0;
            double tax = 0; 
            cout << endl;
            cout << endl;
            cout << endl;
            cout << " Welcome to Bry's Restaurant! " << endl; 
            cout << endl;

            for (x=0; x<2; x++) 
            { 
                cout.precision(2);
                cout << showpoint;
                tax = tax + ((menuList[x].menuPrice) * 0.10); 
                    cout << menuList[x].menuItem << setw(16) << "$ " << menuList[x].menuPrice <<  endl; 
            }
            cout.precision(2);
            cout << showpoint;
            cout<<"     Tax:                         $ " << tax << endl; 
            cout.precision(2);
            cout << showpoint;
            //amount
            for (x=0; x<2; x++) 
            { 
                cout.precision(2);
                cout << showpoint;
                amountTotal = amountTotal +(menuList[x].menuPrice);
            }
            amountTotal = amountTotal + tax;
            cout.precision(3);
            cout << showpoint;
            cout<<"     Amount Total:                  $ " << amountTotal <<endl;
        }
    }
    cout << "\n Thank you for coming to Bry's Restaurant! Have a blessed day!" << endl;
    system ("pause");
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Arrays in C and C++ are 0-based.  You have declared this:

```
menuItemType menuList[8];
```

That means you can index elements 0 to 7.  But you are indexing 1 to 8.  When you read or write to index 8 you will get an access violation.

Comment: If you're lucky you'll get an access violation.  If you're unlucky, something less obviously wrong will happen, and it will be that much harder to track down the bug :(

Answer (score 0):

Array index in C++ starts with 0, not 1.